# Create SQL DB as class and tables as subclasses of DB? with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to get something like this. The last line of the example shows how I want to call the columns - but how can I implement it?

Thanks

```
class db(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.connection....
        self.connection.cursor....


class db_table(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def columns(self):
        return ....

main = db("Main")
sheet = main.db_table("sheet")

headers = main.sheet.columns()
```